# The Correct Change of Variable of an nth Order Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, change-of-variable, laguerre-polynomials

The generalized Laguerre polynomials has the form:

$L_n^m(x):=\dfrac{x^{-m}e^x}{n!}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}(e^{-x}x^{n+m})$

My question is, what will be the $n^{th}$ order derivative when $L_n^m(x)$ is changed to $L_n^m(q^2)$?